# VS2005 immediately runs my older code when an error occurs

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2005, compiler-options

For years, I had this behavior when writing VB.NET code with VS2005:

> If my code contains a syntax error, when I hit F5, a popup would ask
>   something like "do you want to stop... or run a previously compiled
>   version of this code?"

(I would always hit STOP.   Not sure why anyone would want to run a prior edition of their code, instead of the code you are trying to write/fix NOW.)

Yesterday, something changed.   Now even blatant errors like `"callll ThisCodeDoesntExist(xxx.zzz)"` just immediately runs my older code.  No popup.  No choice.  No warning.  No error.  Nothing.

Did I accidentally change some compiler option(s)?   Where would I even begin to look for this?

Comment: might be in your project properties ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm running vs2010 so I'm not sure if there will be any difference but try the following steps:

1. Click 'Tools' in the main toolbar (file, edit... etc.)
2. Click 'Options...'
3. Check 'Show all settings' (on vs2010 this is at the bottom left of the window)
4. Expand 'Projects and Solutions'
5. Click on 'Build and Run'

Then under 'On Run, when build or deployment errors occur:' select 'Prompt to launch'

I assume you're current set up has 'Launch old version' in the combobox. Hope that helps!